# Read/Modify PDF Metadata using iTextSharp without showing any data to user on pdf properties

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, visual-studio-2012, itext

I am trying to use iTextSharp to read/modify PDF metadata. Without showing any information to the user. I gone through below code:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 20f, 20f);
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memStream))
    {
        document.Open(); document.AddSubject("Test"); document.Close();
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any pointers to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippet you are using is about adding metadata to a PDF document that is *created from scratch*. You are asking to *read* metadata from an *existing* PDF document. Please take a look at the documentation on the iText website, more specifically to Q&A entry [How to add / delete / retrieve information from a PDF using a custom property?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-delete-retrieve-information-pdf-using-custom-property)

Granted, the code used in the answer to that question is written in Java, but it's fairly easy to port it to C#. Here's another snippet:

```
public byte[] ManipulatePdf(byte[] src) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
            Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;
            info["Title"] = "Hello World stamped";
            info["Subject"] = "Hello World with changed metadata";
            info["Keywords"] = "iText in Action, PdfStamper";
            info["Creator"] = "Silly standalone example";
            info["Author"] = "Also Bruno Lowagie";
            stamper.MoreInfo = info;
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can retrieve the metadata from an existing PDF through `PdfReader`. You get a `Dictionary` where the keys correspond with the keys of the info dictionary in ISO-32000-1. If you want to change the metadata, you can do so with `PdfStamper`.

This functionality will read and adapt the Info dictionary (which is what you referred to in your code snippet). The PDF can also contains XMP metadata.

XMP metadata can be read like this:

```
public string ReadXmpMetadata(byte[] src) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    byte[] b = reader.Metadata;
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 0, b.Length);
}
```

You can change the XMP metadata like this:

```
public byte[] ManipulatePdf(byte[] src) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
            Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;
            using (MemoryStream msXmp = new MemoryStream()) {
                XmpWriter xmp = new XmpWriter(msXmp, info);
                xmp.Close();
                stamper.XmpMetadata = msXmp.ToArray();      
            }
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I am assuming that you know the difference between the Info dictionary and an XMP metadata stream in PDF.

Comment: In document property window don't want to show value to the user. So how we can hide metadata from pdf file and also wen read that metadata using iTextShapr Library in c#

Comment: You want to remove the metadata. Fine! Replace it with `""` and/or remove the XMP stream. You can't "hide" the metadata, you can only remove it. Please phrase your questions in a language people can understand. I have no idea what you mean when you write "wen read that metadata using iTextShapr Library in c#". Be more accurate!

Comment: thank you for reply. I am hiding Text using PdfLayer. How we can get text from PdfLayer. Here is my code for hiding text using PdfLayer:


PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("Do you see me?", writer);
layer.On = true;


writer is object of PdfWriter class.

Comment: How we can disable copying image from pdf file.

Comment: Is there any ways to hide and get value from itextsharp pdf inc#.

Comment: I don't answer questions posted as comments. The comment section is for comments, not for questions. If you have a question, post it as a question. Your question about metadata was answered (but for some reason you didn't accept my answer).

Comment: Also: your questions are phrased in a way that makes it very hard for people to understand what you're asking. I think it's because you're using `PdfLayer` for the wrong reason. It would help if you explained WHY you want to use `PdfLayer`. Seems to me you're actually trying to add hidden information. Why does it need to be part of the content? Why does it have to be part of the metadata?

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. I can understand, So how we can add hidden information in pdf file using iTextsharp library.

Comment: I gone through your code as above mentioned, In PDF Document Property we can see the metadata details. How we add hidden info in pdf.

Comment: If you want to add hidden info into a PDF, then asking about "metadata" is very misleading, since the concept of "metadata" is described in the PDF standard and it's not what you're looking for. Ask another question and I'll   answer it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Is it possible to validate the xmp metadata before adding it to the pdf??