# Write XMP data to an existing PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xmp

I'm having an issue writing XMP metadata to an existing pdf file in c# using the iTextSharp library. Here's what I have but it's not working. Any suggestions

```
string src = @"C:\test\Test Artifact Document.pdf";

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);


using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
    {
         Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;
         using (MemoryStream msXmp = new MemoryStream())
         {
               XmpWriter xmp = new XmpWriter(msXmp, info);
               xmp.SetProperty(XmpConstants.NsDC, "Firm", "FBI");

               xmp.Close();
               stamper.XmpMetadata = msXmp.ToArray();
         }
     }            
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the issue? How the results differ from what you expect?

Comment: It's not working. When I execute, the file isn't modified.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the code is not saving the changes.
The Stamper writes the changes in the MemoryStream, if you don't save it to a file you are not saving them.

```
        string src = @"C:\test\Test Artifact Document.pdf";

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);


        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
            {
                Dictionary<String, String> info = reader.Info;
                using (MemoryStream msXmp = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    XmpWriter xmp = new XmpWriter(msXmp, info);
                    xmp.SetProperty(XmpConstants.NsDC, "Firm", "FBI");

                    xmp.Close();
                    stamper.XmpMetadata = msXmp.ToArray();
                }
                stamper.Close();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\test\Test Artifact Document (1).pdf", ms.ToArray());
        }
```

Disclaimer: It's my firs time answering here blah blah blah ... don't be too harsh. I'm just answering it cause google brings me here a few times and I can't stand seeing it unanswered anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment.

Check out this answer here:
[Read/Modify PDF Metadata using iTextSharp without showing any data to user on pdf properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950199/read-modify-pdf-metadata-using-itextsharp-without-showing-any-data-to-user-on-pd)

I would start by trying to immediately read the values out of your metadata field and see what you get.  It could be you have updated the pdf in memory stream but something is preventing it from being saved.

Comment: Thanks, that's the post I used to start off with, but modified to fit my needs. That's what's not working lol

Comment: To be clear...Is your outer memory stream (ms) updated?  If so you need to put it somewhere before it closes and disposes.  This answer addresses a different issue but says he can edit and print with his code.  If your memory stream is not updating do you receive an error of any kind?